# Partial display of pdf in iframe of iOS browser

Tags: ios, pdf, iframe

We have a main page in which we are having pdf links. On click of these links the page will redirect to another page which contains iframe. The pdf document will be displayed in that iframe. This scenario is working in other OS other than IOS. In IOS the iframe is showing only the pdf part of screen size. It is not providing scroll bar as well for us to scroll down. We tried changing css Overflow: scroll but did not work.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using iOS 8, there is a bug with displaying PDFs in iframes that basically truncates the PDF file to display only the first page like an image would display. Apple has yet to come out with a fix for this (4+ major releases into iOS 8). This affected an application used by my salesforce in the filed on their tablets/phones so I have to create a work-around. Until Apple fixes their issue this is working for us.

**Interim solution:** Use Google Docs Viewer as pass through for documents
*Little know feature of google docs is the ability to pass through a URL to a PDF. Works like a charm in iOS 8.*

```
//url of your PDF hosted wherever you currently keep it
var pdfurl = 'http://www.manning.com/crowther/HH5aCSS3_SampleCh-01.pdf';
//wrap the url with the google docs gview url
pdfurl = 'http://docs.google.com/gview?url=' + pdfurl + '&embedded=true';
```

Maybe this workaround can help you too.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/Lm1m8wxq/)